# How to do smooth TranslateAnimation

Tags: animation, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I just started on doing android apps in C# with Xamarin.
I'm playing around with animation, but hard to find any good tutorials.
I have made the below code, which works, but instead of a smooth movement, my `irisImageView` just jumps to the position?

How would i move a image smoothly around?

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)

    {

        base.OnCreate (bundle);



        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);



        ImageView faceImageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.faceImageView);

        ImageView irisImageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.irisImageView);


        AnimateIris (irisImageView);

    }



    public void AnimateIris(ImageView iris)

    {

        Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(10,10,150,150);

        anim.Duration = 5000;

        iris.StartAnimation (anim);



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to look at:

1. In your current sample you have `new TranslateAnimation(10,10,150,150)`, which means your animation is starting and ending at the same X and Y coordinates.  Update the ending X and Y position so the animation will occur.
2. You are probably seeing a jump to the position because the image is animating for 5 seconds (but not moving because of the start/end points being the same) and then getting moved to its position as dictated by your Android axml file.  For instance, if your `ImageView` is in the top left corner then I bet it jumps from your starting point up to the top left after 5 seconds.

So first try updating your `TranslateAnimation` and then mess around with where the `ImageView` is situated within your layout!

Comment: ahhh your are right, i have misunderstood the paramters :)
Now it moves correct.

But after the animation it jumps back. some way to keep the new position?

Comment: Great!  Try setting `anim.FillAfter = true;` and see if that prevents it from jumping back.

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks! Btw. know any good places to find tutorials for this stuff?

Comment: You're welcome!  Unfortunately I don't know of any good tutorials... you might look for Android animation tutorials and then try to figure out how to use Xamarin and C# instead of Java.  Otherwise Stack Overflow is a great resource.